# How to make a state space model of en electrical RLC-circuit?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, coil, laplace-transform, homework

I want to learn how to build a state space model of an electrical RLC-cicuit. I don't know how to do that. So I will try here and check if I have done it right.

Focusing on L1:

$$ L_1 \dot{I_1} = U - R_1 I_1 - U_{C1}$$

Kirchoffs first law:

$$ I_1 = C_1 \dot{U_{C1}} + \frac{U_{C1}}{R_2} + \frac{U_{C1}}{R_3}$$

Focusing on C1:
 $$ C_1 \dot{U_{C1}} = $$

And now I'm stuck! Is there a better way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You just need to start with a complete set of equations for your circuit and then do algebraic manipulation until you get the right form. Here's another example asked recently: [Finding state equations for an RL circuit with inductors in T configuration?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/316886/6334)

Comment: Hint: You have 3 energy storage elements, so you need at least 3 equations.

Comment: Thanks! So it will be 3 equations beacuse I have 2 coils and one capacitor?

Comment: I need to define input current/voltage and output current/voltage for them all?

Comment: An inductor or capacitor only has a current through it and a voltage across it. There is  no "input" and "output" current or voltage for a two-terminal element.

Comment: Can I use Maxwell's circulating current theorem to get the current for all those components?

Comment: Yes, either mesh or (modified) nodal analysis will work.